# Use LINQ and lambdas to put string in proper case

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this function called ProperCase that takes a string, then converts the first letter in each word to uppercase.  So ProperCase("john smith") will return "John Smith".  Here is the code:

```
    public string ProperCase(string input)
    {
        var retVal = string.Empty;
        var words = input.Split(' ');

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (word.Length == 1)
            {
                retVal += word.ToUpper();
            }
            else if (word.Length > 1)
            {
                retVal += word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1).ToLower();
            }

            retVal += ' ';
        }

        if (retVal.Length > 0)
        {
            retVal = retVal.Substring(0, retVal.Length - 1);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

This code workds perfectly, but I'm pretty sure I can do it more elegantly with LINQ and lambdas.  Can some please show me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the input string into words, convert each word to title case, and join the converted words back together:

```
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ')
                                      .Select(word => textInfo.ToTitleCase(word))
                                      .ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I added a ToLower to the lambda:

word => textInfo.ToTitleCase(word.ToLower())

Comment: Unnecessary to use Linq here.  textInfo.ToTitleCase(input) does the same thing regardless of number of words.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\b\w", m => m.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on dtb's answer. If you are dealing with c# razor in an cshtml page and need a one liner:

```
@(string.Join(" ", input.ToLower().Split(' ').Select(word => word.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1)).ToArray() ))
```

Or Javascript (could use regex, but this was fun figuring out):

```
var text = input.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word){ return word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, word.length); }).join(" ");
```